# SQL Server 2014 SSIS Excel Source Task import to table date and text to numeric conversion issues

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, type-conversion, data-conversion

Using SQL Server 2014 SSIS to import an vendor supplied Excel file through the Excel Source Data Flow.  Two issues I'm having related to data conversion to the SQL table.

1. In the file is a text column that has prices (numeric values) in it I can't not get it to transform into a numeric field (decimal(8,2)) in SQL.  I have used the Data Conversion data flow task converting it to DT_NUMERIC and it fails to process the field.  I have also tried to let it go through the Data Conversion task and converted through a Derived Column casting the field to Numeric.  Both fail, I'm at a loss as to how to get this into the database in a Decimal/Numeric format.
2. In the same file are three date fields with dates that look like 07/18/2015 in Excel.  I have tried similarly with the Data Conversion and Derived column to get the date into the database as SQL date formats.  I have cast the dates at DT_DBDATE and DT_DBDATE and DT_DBTIMESTANP and neither has worked I have also tried taking the month day and year and rearranging them into the SQL date format with Substring/left/right functions to split the string.  Also to no avail.

Here is what I tried:
Excel Source ---> Data Conversion ----> Derived Column -----> OLE DB Destination
In the excel source it recognized the date as text, I leave that be in the data conversion to deal with it in the Derived Column where I have tried.

a.  (DT_DBDATE)("20" + RIGHT(TRIM(sale_start),2) + "-" + LEFT(TRIM(sale_start),2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(TRIM(sale_start),4,2))  - I have done this with and without the trim with same results.  I have also used Right(sale_start,4).

b.  (DT_DBDATE) sale_start

The SQL table is data type DATE. I have also changed it to DATETIME and used DT_DBTIMESTAMP in place of DT_DBDATE above.

I can't change the file I'm receiving it needs to process into the database the way it comes from the vendor.  Looking at the data in excel there seems to be no reason it wouldn't be ok.

Any direction on bringing this data in would be much appreciated.

2.

Comment: When your data conversion fails, what error does it give?

Comment: What error, and can you give an example of the data that causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out although I don't completely understand what the connection setting is doing.  Similarly with a XML file this connection setting wasn't necessary although some version of a derived column was, I the above I believe in my XML import.

For the EXCEL Solution:
1) In the Excel File connection I added IMEX=1 to the end of the connection under properties. So the connection string looked like this:

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\SSIS\Test.xls;Extended Properties="EXCEL 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";

2) Used the following script in the derived column:

ISNULL([Copy of expected_date]) ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (LEN(TRIM([Copy of expected_date])) == 0 ? NULL(DT_DATE) : (DT_DATE)((DT_DBDATE)TRIM([Copy of expected_date])))

Thanks for taking the time to respond.